# Using Regex to match function calls containing parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been at this all day and I can't figure it out.

Below is a sample data set, I am trying to match every occurence of `foo` and it's contents in parentheses.

```
foo(a, b)
foo(a, (b))
foo((a), (b)), foo((c), (d))
foo((a), (b)), foo(c, d)
```

The best I could come up with is `foo\(.*\)?\)`, but that just captures every line.

EDIT:

What I am specifically trying to do is parse the backgroundImage CSS style from a web page and process it in some way, which I get in the following three example forms:

```
linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, white)
linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, rgba(255,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(to top left, red, blue)
linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, rgba(255,0,0,0)), url('http://example.com/image.jpg')
```

Thus, in my program, I want to parse out each component of the background, and then do something with it. I hope that helps clarify why on earth I want to do something like this!

Comment: How deep are the nested brackets?

Comment: @Denomales, it should not get any deeper than the Line 3 example `foo((a), (b)), foo((c), (d))`, but it can be a combination, like in Line 4: `foo((a), (b)), foo(c, d)`.

Comment: You will need recursive regex (not supported in javascript) or you have to write a parser for this.

Comment: Imagine how quickly you could have solved this if you didn't try to use regexes...

Comment: @user1027169 what are you trying to achieve? What do you intend to do with the matched functions?

Comment: @acdcjunior, I added a little more detail in my post, I hope it is clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the function in the CSS used in your examples, use this regex:

```
\blinear-gradient\(([^()]*|\([^()]*\))*\)
```

It will match one level of nested parenthesis.

[See regex demo here](http://regexr.com?35cf5).

[See JavaScript usage demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/udhwJ/1/).

Comment: Updated the answer based on your question's edit. Should work well.

Answer (score 3):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but you really should consider looking at a proper JavaScript parser if you want to consume anything other than a *very* limited subset of JavaScript. As you've found out, as soon as you want to do anything even remotely useful, regexes become completely impractical.

A good choice would be something like [esprima](https://github.com/ariya/esprima). It's solid, well-documented, and fits in well with other tools because it uses [a standard format](http://esprima.org/doc/index.html#ast) for its results.

You also have to think about the case of scoping - all `foo`s are not equal! Consider the following case:

```
var foo = function foo(a, b) {
  return a + b;
};

var bar = function bar(a, b, c) {
  return foo(a, b) * c;
};

var baz = function baz(a, b, c, d) {
  var foo = function foo(x, y) {
    return x - y;
  };

  return foo(bar(a, b, c), d);
};
```

So yeah, you should probably think about using a real parser instead of trying to cobble together fragile regexes to do this.

Comment: OP doesn't want to parse JS, he wants to parse CSS rules.

Comment: Ah. That wasn't apparent in the question, previously.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
/\bfoo\(.+?\)(?=, foo|$)/g
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vePm4/)